# Installing Gnuplot 5.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnuplot

I have been trying to install Gnuplot 5.0 from source on Ubuntu.

I followed the procedure given in the blog:

[Installing gnuplot from source](http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2010/03/03/install-gnuplot-4-4-0-rc1-on-ubuntu-linux/)

I used the following commands:

```
tar xzf gnuplot-5.0.0.tar.gz
mkdir build
cd build
../gnuplot-5.0.0/configure --with-readline=gnu
make
```

Everything until the configure command works fine. However, I end up getting the following error when I run the make command:

```
In file included from ../../gnuplot-5.0.0/src/qtterminal/QtGnuplotWindow.cpp:187:0:

./ui_QtGnuplotSettings.h:13:25: fatal error: QtGui/QAction: No such file or directory

#include <QtGui/QAction>
```

Could someone guide on how to fix this issue? If there is an alternative easier way to install gnuplot 5.0.0. that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Did you install `qtbase5-dev`? Or any other `qt` library component?

Comment: Yes. I did install qtbase5-dev, qtdeclarative5-dev and libqt5svg5-dev. There are a bunch of qt4 libraries already installed as well, which I did not remove.

Comment: QtGui/QAction means qt4 (QtWidget/QAction in qt5), first install all qt4 dev packages, the recompile (or re-configure too)

Comment: Is there a list of all the qt4 dev packages available?

Comment: I already have libqt4-dev installed. Are they are other qt4 packages that needs to be added?

Comment: I'm not sure which dev packages are all required to build gnuplot with qt, but you can use `./configure --with-qt=no` to build without the qt terminal. You'll still have `wxt` as interactive terminal.

Comment: Thanks. The option --with-qt=no did the trick...gnuplot installed without any issues

Answer (score 12):

Here's a compilation of the various library-dev packages necessary for gnuplot in ubuntu. The package names should be the same under debian, and other distributions based on debian, like Mint. Additional -dev packages that are installed automatically with the ones named are not listed or in (parentheses).

To use external libreadline instead of gnuplot's builtin replacement (recommended)

```
libreadline-dev
```

To have the mathematical functions provided by the cerf library (can't hurt)

```
libcerf-dev
```

For the old interactive `x11`terminal

```
libx11-dev
```

For the `pdfcairo`, `pngcairo`, `epscairo` terminals

```
libcairo2-dev
libpango1-dev
```

additionally for the interactive `wxt` terminal (try `./configure --with-wx-single-threaded` in case of problems (e.g. `make check` crashes). If it doesn't compile with complaints about "XInitThreads", try `TERMLIBS="-lX11" ./configure`.)

```
libwxgtk2.8-dev or libwxgtk3.0-dev
libgtk2.0-dev
```

For the libgd-based `png`, `gif`, `jpeg` bitmap terminals

```
libgd-dev
(libxpm-dev)
(libjpeg-turbo8-dev)
(libtiff5-dev)
```

For the interactive `qt` terminal (`./configure --with-qt=qt5`)

```
qtbase5-dev
libqt5svg5-dev
qttools5-dev-tools  # on Linux Mint (as per comment by Allan below)
```

alternatively for qt4 (`./configure --with-qt=qt4`)

```
libqt4-dev
```

For the `lua` terminal

```
liblua5.2-dev (also read ./INSTALL)
```

For the text-mode `caca` terminal (`./configure --with-caca`)

```
libcaca-dev
```

The list is not final (i don't have a spare system to try out all the dependencies at the moment). Feel free to add, update and correct!

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I just want to add that I also needed to `sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools` in addition to `qtbase5-dev` and `libqt5svg5-dev` to get qt5 terminal in gnuplot. Without this, a linking error `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease: No such file or directory
` occurs. I have edited your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Allan: I can't confirm this with ubuntu 15.04 or .10, What version are you using?

Comment: Well, not exactly Ubuntu, but Linux Mint 17.2.

Comment: They can easily have a different packaging. Split from debian ten years ago.

Comment: Any special options necessary to the configure script, e.g. `--psdir=XYZ`? I'm asking because with the version I build from scratch I get some weird errors sometimes about a postscript prologue file and such. I wonder what the right values are here.

Comment: And btw., I had to do the last compiling step myself, because the compiler flag `-lX11` was missing in the Makefile and I didn't know, where to add it. In case someone has the same problem, here's what make said: `/usr/bin/ld: wxterminal/wxt_gui.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XInitThreads'` and `//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`.

Comment: The x11 library/wxwidgets combination has a know problem, see gnuplot's release notes. Simply run "TERMLIBS="-lX11" ./configure" .But I'd recommend using qt anyway.

Comment: I've never tried postscript with self-compiled gnuplot, but thought it should work out of the box?

Comment: For Redhat based distributions try (tested on CentOS 7.2):

`sudo yum install libX11-devel cairo-devel cairo-tools cairomm-devel cairo pycairo pycairo-devel pango-devel pango pangomm pangomm-devel wxGTK-devel wxGTK3-devel wxGTK wxGTK3 gd-progs gd gd-devel libXpm libXpm-devel libjpeg-turbo libjpeg-turbo-utils turbojpeg libjpeg-turbo-devel libjpeg-turbo-static libtiff libtiff-devel libtiff-static libtiff-tools qt5-qtbase qt5-qtbase-devel qt5-qtbase-static lua lua-devel lua-static caca-utils libcaca libcaca-devel readline readline-devel readline-static texlive-subfigure`

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04, I had to use `libpango1.0-dev` instead of `libpango1-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

I simply followed the instructions in the file INSTALL and it worked perfectly:

```
$ tar xzf gnuplot-5.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd gnuplot-5.0.1
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After doing this, when I call gnuplot anywhere, the result is

```
$ gnuplot

G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 1    last modified 2015-06-07 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
```

Comment: That's very nice for you (although you likely now have a gnuplot with only one useful terminal, postscript), but doesn't help with the problem.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.04, and had previously installed gnuplot 4.6 from the repository. I instaled gnuplot 5.01 without unistalling gnuplot 4.6. Maybe, for that reason, it installed all necessary packages. Anyway, I have all terminals working and if I don't set any terminal, it opens a window and shows the graphic in a x11 terminal.

Comment: You most certainly don't have the wxt or qt terminal, or any of the *cairo terminals. Unless you previously installed the qt, cairo and pango dev-packages for something else. There is no automatism. The x11 terminal still works, but I don't think you'll want it back once you've seen the alternatives. Ubuntu has a package gnuplot5 if you want to try.

Comment: This being a top hit for "install gnuplot" it was useful to me to have the basics summarized here, together with Karl's last comment.