# gnuplot 5.0.2 no qt terminal

Tags: qt, gnuplot

I am trying to install the newest gnuplot 5.0.2 o on Ubuntu 14.04 with the qt terminal but it seems not to work. The configure says

> Qt terminal: no (use --with-qt or --with-qt=qt4 to enable

I tried to install all the packages listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526044/installing-gnuplot-5-0-on-ubuntu) but the line stays the same, neither qt5 or qt4 works.

I can install gnuplot 4.6 from packet manager which has both, qt4 and wxt.
So what package is missing or what do I do wrong?

Comment: Search the `config.log` for `Qt`, there must be some messages about what is missing. Then use `apt-file search` to find the missing packages.

Comment: I did not find any missing packages, but I have found this: configure:14154: WARNING: No C++ compiler found. The Qt terminal will not be compiled.  I am pretty sure I have a c++ compiler gcc -v:  gcc version 5.3.0 20151204 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04)

Comment: Hey Christoph, thanks for your answer anyways. Seems I just forgot to link c++ to g++ ! now it works fine!

Comment: @Namal If you figured out how to fix your problem, post your solution as an answer (you are allowed and even encouraged to answer your own questions), and mark it as the accepted answer.